# How to get past the stone head in Karthspire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in a room in Karthspire with this huge head. There aren't any obvious things to trigger except for several plates on the ground about the location where my character is located in the following figure.

[image]

Any ideas on how to get past this room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seal on the ground is bound to react to the Dragonborn blood.

It is automatically activated when you step on it if I remember. It is possible thought that you need a specific quest for it. You should be accompanied by Delphine and Esbern at this time. It's part a a quest series to defeat the main opponent. You are going to Sky Haven to learn about history.

Comment: Right, well I don't have either have either with me, so I guess I should go find the quest line to pick them up

Answer (score 2):

For those that find themselves at this point, and 'guessed' their way through the first bridge puzzle, quickly reload as this creates a serious **bug** in the game later part of the main quest line.

You will find it to be a royal pain in the butt when the 2 people part of the quest get stuck and just stand there at the first bridge puzzle.

So reload prior to solving this puzzle if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For most of the puzzles the guy accompanying you says most of the answers, so listen carefully. When you are **with them** in the room, I had to activate something on that stone tablet you stand on.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You are answering a question that already had an accepted answer two years ago. This question probably doesn't need another answer--perhaps look at some more recent questions or use the 'Unanswered' tab at the top of the page to find questions that haven't yet been answered.